# How to calculate alpha y beta angles in this "simple" graph?

Tags: geometry

i wanna know how calculate $\alpha$ y $\beta$ from $a$, $R$, $r$ and $\varphi$. As you can see, both have their respective formula, but i don't know how to get to them (the process)

[image]

The pdf is mine, but I did the analysis 2 years ago, and as much as I have tried to do it again, I have not been successful. I have tried with analytical geometry, mostly for a graphical representation of the problem, but, although I get results close to what I would get if I used the formulas in the image, the process involved is very long and complicated compared to just using the formulas.

If someone can think of how to get to the formulas, from the 4 terms I mentioned at the beginning, I would appreciate if you could describe the process step by step, since that is what I need, given that the formulas work perfectly (I checked them graphically).

Thank you

This image shows how to get $\phi$:

[image]

Modified diagram including the missing information

[image: ModifiedDiagram]

Comment: Not clear what those angles ($\alpha,\beta$) represent

Comment: Sorry @Andrei . $alpha$ represent the angle between blue arrow and the horizontal green line (x'), and $beta$ represent the angle between red arrow and the horizontal green line (x'). You can see this in the first image.

Comment: OK, I see that, but what are those arrows? I mean, there is no information in your problem to relate $\alpha$ or $\beta$ with anything

Comment: @Andrei We added a modified diagram, which includes missing and/or unclear information.

Comment: Thank you very much YNK... @Andrei , the diagram represents a belt drive between two pulleys. The arrows represent the forces that are transmitted from the belt to the shaft at the center of the pulley. The image is a case in which the sheaves are not aligned horizontally, as they are in most cases, so to decompose the forces, it is necessary to consider the offset angle (φ) between the xy coordinate system and the new x'y' coordinate system and the ϕ angle [(R-r)/a]. Finally, "r": small radio, "R": large radio and "a" is the distance between pull's centers.

Comment: The modified diagram looks like it might be misleading. Is the red arrow supposed to be parallel to the red line tangent to the larger pulley, or is it supposed to connect the center of the large pulley to the point where the belt is tangent to the smaller pulley as the diagram seems to indicate? A similar question applies to the blue arrow and the other blue line.

Comment: @DavidK Your doubts about the modified diagram are duly note. We drew the modified diagram before OP posted his second comment in which OP describes the diagram as a belt drive between two pulleys. This is totally different scenario from two circles with their common tangents. We were not aware that those arrows represent forces. We hope OP would soon speak up after reading your and our comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basing this answer on the assumption that the blue arrow is parallel to the blue tangent line and the red arrow is parallel to the red tangent line.
If this assumption is false, the formulas for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the question are not correct.

I labeled some points in the modified diagram to help name angles.

[image]

You want to find the two angles $\alpha = \lvert \angle POS\rvert$
and $\beta= \lvert \angle QOS\rvert$.

By the assumption that the red and blue arrows are parallel to the red and blue tangent lines, respectively, it follows that they make right angles with the corresponding radii, that is $\lvert \angle POV\rvert = \lvert \angle QOT\rvert = 90^\circ$.

You can show that
$$\phi = \lvert \angle MOV\rvert = \lvert \angle MOT\rvert = \arccos \dfrac{R - r}{a}$$
by dropping a perpendicular from $M$ to the radius $OV$ or $OT$.
This is diagrammed in another answer so I omit it from the diagram.
You also know that $\varphi = \arcsin \dfrac Ha$.

Then
$$\lvert \angle SOT\rvert = \lvert \angle MOT\rvert - \lvert \angle MOS\rvert
 = \phi - \varphi. $$
Therefore
$$\beta = \lvert \angle QOT\rvert - \lvert \angle SOT\rvert 
= 90^\circ - (\phi - \varphi) = 90^\circ + \varphi - \phi .$$

Also
\begin{multline}
\alpha = \lvert \angle TOV\rvert - \lvert \angle SOT\rvert - \lvert \angle POV\rvert\\
= 2\phi - (\phi - \varphi) -  90^\circ = \phi + \varphi - 90^\circ
= 2\varphi  - 90^\circ + \varphi - \phi =  2\varphi - \beta. 
\end{multline}

Comment: Thanks @David k , this is exactly what i need !. I should have specified that the red and blue lines were parallel, respectively, sorry. Thanks for your solution, it is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

( being very brief .. to guide per new norms.)

Forget the circle of  radius $R$... why?

At first *you need only draw a simpler starting sketch* with line of centers horizontal. You have

$$ (\alpha, \beta)= 0\pm \sin^{-1}(r/a)$$

and after rotation of line of centers through angle $ \varphi$ the required angles are:

$$ (\alpha, \beta)= \varphi \pm \sin^{-1}(r/a).$$

Comment: Hi @Narasimham , I think what you say is true, but by replacing the values, I arrive at the following: $\frac{R-r}{a} = \frac{r}{a}$, which is related to my concern: Is it correct to ignore the value of R in this case? as you point out.

Comment: which means you get  $ R=2 r$ when $R$ itself is not relevant !

Answer (score 1):

[image: TwoPulleys]

After seeing your derivation of $\space\angle \phi\space$ in terms of $\space R$, $\space r,\space$and $\space a$, we thought of posting this to show you that the same derivation can be accomplish in fewer steps.

We reproduce here your $2^\text{nd}$ diagram after adding the point $K$ on the line segment $FE$. Now consider $\triangle EKB$. Since you have drawn $BK$ parallel to $AF$, $\measuredangle EKB=90^o$. Therefore,
$$\cos\left(\phi\right) = \dfrac{R-r}{a}.$$

Comment: Thanks again @YNK , this way is more intuitive and practical.

Answer (score 0):

In the modified diagram, let's choose the x axis direction from the center of the big circle towards the small circle's center. Then we use the position of the small center circle to be $(a,0)$. The angle between the radius $r$ and the $x$ axis is $\phi$ (which you just calculated), so the position of the intersection of the $r$ and the circle is at $(a+r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$. Then the angle between the blue arrow and the x axis is given by $$\tan^{-1}\frac{r\sin\phi}{a+r\cos\phi}$$
I think you can take it from here.